# Parallel.For maximum threads and current thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

What I want to achieve:

Using `Parallel.For` (anything else would be appreciated, but found out that this one is the easiest) I want to increase a variable named `max` so that it gets to `100,000,000`, using threads, but the program should use only X number of threads at the same time.

**Code snippet:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace pool_threading
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static int max=0;
            static int current_max_thread=0;
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            Parallel.For(0, 100000000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 },
            i =>
            {
                            max++;
                if(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId>current_max_thread)
                               current_max_thread=Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            });

            Console.WriteLine ("I got to this number {0} using most {1} threads",max,current_max_tread);
        }
        public static void GetPage(int i)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

**Result:**

**I got this number `38,786,886` using most 11 threads**

Now ... I don't know why I get the number `38,786,886` which is less than `38,786,886`, but I guess it's because multiple threads are trying to increase it at the exact same time, so if 10 are trying at the same time, only the first one will get the chance. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

The biggest "problem" is that I get 11 threads all the time, even with the maximum set to 50 (scroll the code to see the maximum), if I set it to maximum 1 thread, I get always 4 (maybe 4 is the minimum in this situation, but it still doesn't explain why I get maximum only 11 at the same time).

Comment: Why do you need exactly `X` number of threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here, as far as I can see:

First, you are hammering away on `max` from multiple threads. You probably have a multicore machine. Those operations are probably overlapping with each other. To perform your incrementing in a thread safe way you need

```
   Interlocked.Increment(ref max);
```

not

```
   max++;   /* not thread safe */
```

Second, you don't always get the number of threads you asked for in `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. You'll never get more, but you might get less.

If you're going to use parallelism please pay close attention to the thread-safety of the code you'll run in the threads.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial, just use `i` inside of the loop instead of trying to increment and use `max`.  You're not incrementing it safely, but there's not reason for you to try.  The whole *point* of `Parallel.For` is that it gives you the loop index, and ensures that each loop index is hit exactly once, no more, no less.

Comment: I just want to run for example a function 1000 times, but with X number of threads at the same time, not 1 thread, and not 1000 threads. Plus, with i instead of max it works.

Comment: @icebox19 Then use a parallel for.  That's what it's there for, and that's what it'll do.

Comment: that's what I'm using, but it's not going over 11 threads at the same time

Comment: @icebox19 Sure, and why should it?  It's going to optimize itself to use as many threads as will provide the best throughput.  In most cases this'll be less than you think it should be.  Generally just a few more threads than cores is as many as you'll want.  Creating additional threads is just wasting resources and increasing contention.  Using something that will handle this automatically is almost always better than handling it manually; you usually don't know best.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not getting 50 threads for 2 main reasons:

1. Hardware. There is a point at which a processor can do more with fewer threads because the time it takes to switch threads is more than just running a thread more often. This leads to
2. Managed code. C#.NET is a managed code system. The programmers of .Net know the above and probably set some limits and checks to prevent too many threads from running. What you are setting in the code might be above some internal limit, so it is effectively ignored. Also, you are setting a maximum, so the Parallel.For() can use anywhere from 1 to X number of threads, whatever it thinks is most efficient.